# Problem with Ubuntu Server USB Install

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, uefi, bios

I am currently using a hardware running on Intel E7400 processor bought second hand and previously installed with Windows XP Pro which is unable to be booted as there was [OS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9qNs.jpg). Which I found out from the owner that she removed the other hard disk which carried personal information.

I wanted to install ubuntu server on it and I have tried two ways to do so. I haven't touched the debugging of the linux files yet but just looking if there is any way to fix the problem. I have used the same USB to install Ubuntu server on another computer and there was no issues.

Anyway here is my problem:
Initially I tried to install using the 18.04.1 LTS which is met with this [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47mgJ.jpg) which I circumvented by unplugging my keyboard and usb then, plugging my usb in again without the keyboard. Which brings me to the installer screen. Apparently the installer was reading my keyboard.

Then the next problem came: The installer just loops to the language screen after I selected done on network configuration.This is 
[before I connected the LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ge1e.jpg), 
[after I connected the LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNw5G.jpg), 
Somehow no ‘bond’ was created?
[before it loops to the choose language screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY28a.jpg).

[LAN connection was fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLaoS.jpg) 
[I am using an unmanaged switch here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJaAS.jpg)

Then, I saw online that the alternative download may help and therefore I tried the alternative download. I used both ISO and dd images and it still leads to this [new problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpmdA.jpg)

How should I solve either problem whichever easier so as to get ubuntu server up and running?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am a noobie here. Please forgive me for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved by simply installing with the ISO burned into an actual DVD.